# 26 digits of number in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interesting problem in my application. I create a banking application and store a 26 digit account number in the database.

In the MySQL database, I use the `decimal(26,0)` data type but I need this number to be generated in my NodeJS application from typescript.

I've come up with this solution, but it does not generate a 26 digit account number:

```
  /**
   * Generate unique account bill
   */
  async getAccountBill(): Promise<Bill | number> {
    const accountBill = (
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000000000000000000) +
        10000000000000000000 * 100000
    );

    console.log(accountBill); // 1.0000387421390274e+24
    console.log(typeof accountBill); // number

   /** 
    * Checking if the generated account number already exists in the database
    */
    const isAccountBill = await this.getByAccountBill(accountBill);
    return isAccountBill ? await this.getAccountBill() : accountBill;
  }
```

I can also change the type to string, but it does not match my database model, so I'd rather return a number type.

Comment: Use a [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) instead of a `number`, if your runtime supports it?  Or just use a `string`... you're not doing math with it, are you?  Then it's more of a `string` than a `number`, no matter how you have it represented in the db

Answer (score 0):

```js
let random261 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000000);
let random262 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000000);
let rand26 = `${random261}${random262}`;

//Then in mysql you can do this
CAST(rand26 as DECIMAL(26,0));

Not tested though.
```